# show duplicate rows in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have this table

**`MEN`**

```
id    |   Qty   |  Place
========================
111   |  10     |  55
111   |  20     |  66
111   |  10     |  77
222   |  40     |  11
333   |  50     |  11
111   |  10     |  22
222   |  44     |  33
222   |  40     |  44
333   |  15     |  55
```

i need to show all the records that id=id and Qty=Qty  like this:

```
id    |   Qty  |  Place
=====================
111   |  10    |  55
111   |  10    |  77
111   |  10    |  22
222   |  40    |  11
222   |  40    |  44
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT T.ID,T.Qty
FROM Table1 T
GROUP BY T.ID,T.Qty
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));
```

Use Below query to get full set of record details:

```
SELECT R.Id, R.Qty, R.Place
FROM Table1 R INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT T.Id, T.Qty
 FROM Table1 T
 GROUP BY T.Id, T.Qty
 HAVING (((Count(*))>1))
)AS JR ON R.Qty = JR.Qty AND R.Id = JR.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT MEN.Id, MEN.Qty, MEN.Place
FROM MEN INNER JOIN
(SELECT MEN.Id, MEN.Qty
 FROM MEN
 GROUP BY MEN.Id, MEN.Qty
 HAVING (((Count(*))>1)))  AS a
ON (MEN.Qty = a.Qty) AND (MEN.Id = a.Id)
ORDER BY MEN.Id, MEN.Qty;
```

Create the inner query to find where there are more than one instances of the Id then join it back to the original table to get the Place values.