# delete duplicate rows from my table

Tags: sql, ms-access

i need to delete all duplicate rows in my table - but leave only one row

```
MyTbl
====
Code     |  ID  |  Place  |  Qty  |  User
========================================
1        |  22 |   44     |  34   |  333
2        |  22 |   44     |  34   |  333
3        |  22 |   55     |  34   |  333
4        |  22 |   44     |  34   |  666
5        |  33 |   77     |  12   |  999
6        | 44  |   11     |  87   |  333
7        | 33  |   77     |  12   |  999
```

i need to see this:

```
Code    | ID  |  Place  |  Qty  |  User
=======================================
1       | 22 |   44     |  34   |  333
3       | 22 |   55     |  34   |  333
4       | 22 |   44     |  34   |  666
5       | 33 |   77     |  12   |  999
6       | 44 |   11     |  87   |  333
```

Comment: Do you have any id on each row at all that is unique?

Comment: Select unique rows into a temp table. Truncate the original and insert from the temp table again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show duplicate rows in access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363914/show-duplicate-rows-in-access)

Answer (score 2):

In most databases, the fastest way to do this is:

```
select distinct t.*
into saved
from mytbl;

delete from mytbl;

insert into mytbl
    select *
    from saved;
```

The above syntax should work in Access.  Other databases would use `truncate table` instead of `delete`.

Comment: can i get more detail ? it is not understandable for me

Comment: @Gold . . . This copies the data into another table.  It then deletes all the rows in `mytbl` and puts the distinct rows back in.  This preserves all the security and index features of the original table and removes duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
 WITH CTEMyTbl (A,duplicateRecCount)
    AS
    (  
    SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by id,place,qty,us  ORDER BY id)
    AS duplicateRecCount   
    FROM MyTbl
    )
    DELETE FROM CTEMyTbl
    WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```